# Multiplying columns in a visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

If I have a matrix visual where one column is a percentage of column total (where filters can change the output), how can I multiply that by another column within the matrix?

For example, if I’m multiplying the forecast error of an item (column in an existing table) by the percentage of sales dollars (which would appear as “%CT sales dollars)?

Edit: adding screenshots.

In the first screenshot you see that we have "products" and their sales dollars are marked as a percentage of the column total.

In the second screenshot, you see that the dollars column still totals 100%, even if the matrix is filtered. However, the forecast error column is unaffected by the filter, because the forecast error is at the product level.

How do we create a third column that multiplies the two numeric columns together? IE- dollar percentage times forecast error percentage?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Three measures need to be created. Here is the dax code:

```
Step 1 = SUM('Sheet1'[Dollars])
Step 2 = CALCULATE(Sheet1[Step 1],ALLSELECTED(Sheet1[Product]))
Step 3 = DIVIDE('Sheet1'[Step 1], 'Sheet1'[Step 2],0)
```

[image: Solution]